# Running program within gdb debugger in Vagrant Linux environment results in Permission Denied error 126

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb, vagrant

I have a Vagrant Virtual Machine running in Linux Ubuntu 18.04. I have compiled a program (we'll call it program1) that has multiple files and a couple of libraries. All of the code, libraries and compiled executable files are in the same directory. The code compiles fine with my make file, which includes the "-g" flag for each file it compiles. I can run program1 with the command "./program1" with no issues. Here are the commands I use to start the debugger:

```
gdb ./program1
run
```

After I execute the "run" command above, I get the following errors:

```
/bin/bash: /vagrant/pr1/program1: Permission denied
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: /vagrant/pr1/program1: cannot execute: Permission denied
During startup program exited with code 126
```

This seems to be a common error, but I've tried other recommended solutions but they have not worked:

1. I have verified the user has permissions to run the program because I can run it directly using "./program1"
2. I have verified the logged in user account has root permissions
3. I have changed directories to the folder for .gdbinit and run chmod +x .gdbinit
4. also tried adding "set auto-load safe-path" in .gdbinit

One other clue is that I also tried running with Visual Studio code and I get the same error. However, if I sit there and try it 10 or 20 times, it eventually works.

Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: try running gdb with `sudo`

Comment: When I saw the answer, I thought that would surely work. However, I just tried to run: sudo gdb ./program1 gdb started, but I still get the error 126 when I select "run" within gdb to start the debugging.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I did not understand how Vagrant works, but apparently the /Vagrant folder is shared with the host virtual environment, which in my case was VirtualBox. Vagrant synchronizes this shared folder with VirtualBox, which was causing some permission problems when trying to run gdb. To resolve the issue, I moved all my code to the /home folder, which is not under the /Vagrant folder and now everything works perfectly with gdb and Visual Studio Code.